# Provide password to SSOCONFIG.EXE as parameter?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, sysprep

How can you provide the password to `ssoconfig.exe -restoresecret` as parameter?

I'm trying to use the sysprep scripts from Colin Meade on [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21783.sysprep-biztalk-server-2010.aspx)

Checked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560589.aspx) and `ssoconfig -restoresecret` only has `<restore file>` as a parameter ... no reference to "password"

Yet when I run the command, I get the prompt for a password, along with the password hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560589.aspx, the command does not let you restore a secret with a password as a parameter. So it doesn't seem to be viable via the command line.

I don't know what the use-case is in your case, but in general I'm not sure if this would be something you want to automate?

What you can do is automate it yourself by writing a wrapper (e.g. console application) for it. You can do so by sending keystrokes to the command line, there are various examples available here on SO.

Comment: My use case is sysprep'ing a BizTalk virtual machine, and trying to automate as much as possible. I was hoping I was missing a quick fix ... I'll see about using something like AutoHotKey to drive it